# How speed of light is absolute/constant if time (denominator) is relative?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

Speed is path / time.

How speed of light in vacuum can be always constant if denominator (time) is relative, its changing?

If speed of light must be constant then path must be changed as well?

Answer (score 3):

You have this the wrong way around. Time changes because the speed of light is constant. Consider this simple thought experiment, bearing in mind that the speed of light is always 299 792 458 metres per second...

You and I stand together and flash a light to the east and west at t=0. At t=1, the light is exactly 299 792 458 metres away from us in each direction.

Now we repeat the experiment, but this time you walk after the light to the east at about 1m/s while I stand still. In my frame at t=1 the light is 299 792 458 metres away from me in each direction as before. But from your perspective, the light to the east is about a metre closer because you have been walking after it, while the light to the west is about a metre further away because you have been walking away from it. So the distance light has travelled to the east of you is less than the distance light has travelled to the west of you. The only way that can be true, if the speed of light is constant, is if the time where the light is to the east is slightly less than t=1 in your frame, and if the time where the light is to the west is slightly more than t=1 in your frame. So the time in your frame has to be different from the time in mine, to compensate for the fact that the light has travelled different distances in your frame than it has in mine.

Comment: Distance and time always change in such a way that their ratio stay constant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the length does change as well. This is called "length contraction". Space and time are linked, so any changes to how we measure one will also affect the other. The exact formula for how they are linked is called the [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) and actually predates Einstein's special relativity.

Comment: it is more than just length contraction, even in Newtonian physics two different frames will disagree on the path length of the light. In most cases, the path length is only minimally affected by length contraction, most of the difference is Newtonian

Comment: Whoops, yes, of course you're right Dale that the biggest contribution to the light path change is simply the (relative) motion of the frames.